# Transpose rows to columns using decod - How'sthe performance?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, transpose

I have found many examples on this max (decode) technique known as pivoting, se example below.
Does anyone have experience using this on large datasets? How does it preform?

```
    CREATE TABLE po_table (
    po_num NUMBER,
    terms_type NUMBER,
    terms_description VARCHAR2(20)
    );

    INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(10, 1, 'Desc-10-1');
    INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(10, 2, 'Desc-10-2');
    INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(10, 3, 'Desc-10-3');
    INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(20, 1, 'Desc-20-1');
    INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(20, 3, 'Desc-20-3');
    INSERT INTO po_table VALUES(30, NULL, NULL);

    COMMIT;

    SELECT
    po_num,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 1, terms_type)) AS terms1,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 1, terms_description)) AS terms1Desc,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 2, terms_type)) AS terms2,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 2, terms_description)) AS terms2Desc,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 3, terms_type)) AS terms3,
    MAX(DECODE(terms_type, 3, terms_description)) AS terms3Desc
    FROM
    po_table
    GROUP BY po_num
    ORDER BY po_num;
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason not to use native `PIVOT` clause (assuming that you are on 11g version)?

Answer (score 0):

Tried on Exadata X2-2 full rack with 10mio rows, 3 distinct groups, runs in 16s. Used it before on 500mio rows, not a big issue.

Why not use pivot clause? It still has nasty bugs (not fixed in 11.2.0.4).

Comment: Can you please refer some details about those bugs? I use it occasionally and so far I did not spot any.

Comment: You will get error:ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
If you don't have spotted it, that's OK, if you get it, there's a patch available

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Jörg, currently I have only 120 000 value-rows to transpose and only about 30 types, so far so good. It has run in production a few years now without any issues. It will take some time before we hit the million mark.